# How to Install VmWare's VM as independent Operating System

Tags: linux, vmware, openstack

I have `Ubuntu 12.01 Server` installed inside `VMWare WorkStation 10` and have `OpenStack` cloud deployed in it.

What I want to do is that install this created VM in my system as an independent OS.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking to take your virtual and make it physical (V2P). If so this is difficult because the OS is setup to run against virtual hardware and won't be configured for your physical hardware. It is a better practice to do a fresh install of the OS and move your application and configuration to the new install.

If you are determined to try it anyway you can take an image of the OS and write it to the HD.